# IE11 issue with creating JSfiddle for another issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a JSFiddle to show the problem I am having in IE11 but when i setup the JSFiddle in IE11 its not even showing my fields that pop up when choosing a report. Can someone please help me get this JSFiddle working properly?

My real problem I am having is when I hit the submit button and my selects are not chosen if I hit the add all button and hit submit in IE11 it does not count as being selected and still want a selection from the select. This is only in IE11 though and works in FireFox and Chrome. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated since my office only allows programs to be written in IE :(

https://jsfiddle.net/bobrierton/b1bds5h1/

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="15" style="width: 600px">
    <tr>
        <td><span class="srch_title" for="reporttype">Please select a report:</span>
            <select class="form-control" id="reporttype" name="reporttype"> 
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select Report</option>
                <option id ="checklistreports" value="checklistreports" >Checklist Stats</option>
                <option id ="locationreports" value="locationreports" >Location Stats</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<form name="generatereport" method="post">

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="15" style="width: 600px">
    <tr>
        <td id="location" style="display: none;">
            <select name="Location" id="loc" multiple="multiple" size="9">
                <option value="OPERATIONS">Operations</option>
                <option value="CCC">Contact Center</option>
                <option value="QA">QA Department</option>
                <option value="DS">DeSoto</option>
                <option value="PS">Palma Sola</option>
                <option value="LWR">Lakewood Ranch</option>
                <option value="NR">North River</option>
                <option value="SDL">SDL</option>
                <option value="FSC">FSC</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td id="locationbtns" style="display: none;">
            <button id="add" type="button">ADD ALL</button>
            <button id="rem" type="button">REMOVE ALL</button>
        </td>
        <td id="locationtextarea" style="display: none;">
            <textarea id="selected" rows="9" readonly></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="employeelist" style="display: none;">
            <select name="EmployeeName" id="EmployeeName" multiple="multiple" size="9">
                <option value="OPERATIONS">Operations</option>
                <option value="CCC">Contact Center</option>
                <option value="QA">QA Department</option>
                <option value="DS">DeSoto</option>
                <option value="PS">Palma Sola</option>
                <option value="LWR">Lakewood Ranch</option>
                <option value="NR">North River</option>
                <option value="SDL">SDL</option>
                <option value="FSC">FSC</option>
            </select>
            <!---<cfquery name="GetActiveEmps" datasource="tco_associates">
                SELECT assoc_userid, assoc_last, assoc_first FROM tco_associates
                WHERE assoc_status = 'ACTIVE' 
                and assoc_last NOT LIKE 'Test%' 
                and len(assoc_last) > 0 
                ORDER BY assoc_last
            </cfquery>    

            <select name="EmployeeName" id="EmployeeName" multiple="multiple" size="9">
                <cfoutput query="GetActiveEmps">
                    <option value="#assoc_userid#">#Trim(assoc_last)#, #Trim(assoc_first)#</option>
                </cfoutput>
            </select>--->
        </td>
        <td id="employeelistbtns" style="display: none;">
            <button id="add1" type="button">ADD ALL</button>
            <button id="rem1" type="button">REMOVE ALL</button>
        </td>
        <td id="employeelisttextarea" style="display: none;">
            <textarea id="selected1" rows="9" readonly></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="15" style="width: 600px">
    <tr>
        <td id="chosendates" style="display: none;">
            <span class="srch_title" for="StartDate">From:</span>
            <input type='text' name="StartDate" id="StartDate" value="" required/>

            <span class="srch_title" for="EndDate">To:</span>
            <input type='text' name="EndDate" id="EndDate" value="" required/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="formattype" style="display: none;">
            <span class="srch_title" for="Format">Format:</span>
            <select name="Format" required>
                <option selected value="">Select Format</option>
                <option value="print">Print</option>
                <option value="pdf">Preview</option>
                <option value="xls">Excel</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="submitbtn" style="display: none;">
            <input type="button" onclick="javascript:window.location='index.cfm?content=reports';" value="Cancel" />
            <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Continue" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

function resetDatePickers(){
      var today   = new Date();
      var weekAgo = new Date();
      var $from   = $("#StartDate");
      var $to     = $("#EndDate");

      weekAgo.setDate(today.getDate() - 7);

      $from.datepicker({  
        changeMonth: true,
        maxDate: today,
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
          $to.datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
        }
      }).datepicker('setDate', weekAgo);

      $to.datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        maxDate: today,
        minDate: weekAgo,
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
          $from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", dateText);
        }
      }).datepicker('setDate', today);
    }


    $(document).on('change', '#reporttype', function() {
        var value = $(this).val();

        var location             = $("#location");
        var loc                  = $("#loc");
        var employeelist         = $("#employeelist");
        var chosendates          = $("#chosendates");
        var formattype           = $("#formattype");
        var submitbtn            = $("#submitbtn");
        var locationbtns         = $("#locationbtns");
        var locationtextarea     = $("#locationtextarea");
        var EmployeeName         = $("#EmployeeName");
        var employeelistbtns     = $("#employeelistbtns");
        var employeelisttextarea = $("#employeelisttextarea");
        var generatereportform   = $("form[name=generatereport]");

        if (value === "checklistreports") {
            generatereportform[0].reset();
            location.show();
            locationbtns.show();
            locationtextarea.show();
            loc.prop('required',true);
            employeelistbtns.show();
            employeelisttextarea.show();
            employeelist.show();
            chosendates.show();
            formattype.show();
            submitbtn.show();
            generatereportform.attr("action", "index.cfm?content=reportsassociate");
            EmployeeName.prop('required',true);
        } else if (value === "locationreports") {
            generatereportform[0].reset();
            location.show();
            locationbtns.show();
            locationtextarea.show();
            loc.prop('required',true);
            employeelistbtns.hide();
            employeelisttextarea.hide();
            employeelist.hide();
            chosendates.show();
            formattype.show();
            submitbtn.show();
            generatereportform.attr("action", "index.cfm?content=reportslocation");
            EmployeeName.prop('required',false);
        } else {
            generatereportform[0].reset();
            location.hide();
            locationbtns.hide();
            locationtextarea.hide();
            loc.prop('required',false);
            employeelistbtns.hide();
            employeelisttextarea.hide();
            employeelist.hide();
            chosendates.hide();
            formattype.hide();
            submitbtn.hide();
            generatereportform.attr("action", "#");
            EmployeeName.prop('required',false);
        }

    resetDatePickers()
        });

 // JS for Showing Chosen Locations in textarea

    // Listens to the changes in #loc. Prepares the selected elements, and sets the result in
    // #selected.
    $("#loc").change(function() {
      var selected = [];

      $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
        selected.push($(this).text());
      });

      $("#selected").val(selected.join("\n"));
    });

    // Selects all the options, and manually triggers the change() of #loc
    $("#add").click(function() {
      var loc = $("#loc");
      loc.find("option").prop("selected", true);
      loc.change();
    });

    // Deselects all the options, and manually triggers the change() of #loc
    $("#rem").click(function() {
      var loc = $("#loc");
      loc.find("option").prop("selected", false);
      loc.change();
    });
    // End JS for Showing Chosen Locations in textarea

    // JS for Showing Chosen Associates in textarea

    // Listens to the changes in #EmployeeName. Prepares the selected elements, and sets the 
    // result in #selected1.
    $("#EmployeeName").change(function() {
      var selected = [];

      $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
        selected.push($(this).text());
      });

      $("#selected1").val(selected.join("\n"));
    });

    // Selects all the options, and manually triggers the change() of #EmployeeName
    $("#add1").click(function() {
      var emps = $("#EmployeeName");
      emps.find("option").prop("selected", true);
      emps.change();
    });

    // Deselects all the options, and manually triggers the change() of #EmployeeName
    $("#rem1").click(function() {
      var emps = $("#EmployeeName");
      emps.find("option").prop("selected", false);
      emps.change();
    });
    // End JS for Showing Chosen Associates in textarea
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Try changing `id="location"` to something else. Element IDs become global variables, so this conflicts with `window.location`.